# How to implement seekbar discrete with replacing tick mark from dot to numbers in navigation drawer . Is it possible at all

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, navigation-drawer, seekbar

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:thumb="@drawable/ic_circle"
    android:max="7"
    android:progress="3"/>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBU9Z.jpg

How to implement seekbar discrete with replacing tick mark from dot to numbers in navigation drawer . Is it possible at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play with values and use enum :

```
public static final String VAL1 = "A8";
public static final String VAL2 = "A1";
public static final String VAL3 = "A5";
public static final String VAL4 = "A1";

public static enum Suit { VAL1, VAL2, VAL3, VAL4 }
    
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) 
{
     progressChangedValue = progress;
     setProgresValue(Suit(progressChangedValue));
}
```

Or use a library like https://github.com/warkiz/IndicatorSeekBar